# Adding Event Listeners in constructor

Tags: javascript, events, object, constructor

```
function Foo(elementId, buttonId) {
this.element = document.getElementById(elementId);
this.button = document.getElementById(buttonId);
this.bar = function() {dosomething};
this.button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {this.bar();}, false);
}

var myFoo = new Foo('someElement', 'someButton');
```

I'd like to add event listeners inside my constructor, but it doesn't seem to work. Is this something that's possible with the correct syntax? I always get hung up on the line:

```
this.button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {this.bar();}, false);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `this` value changes in the constructor. You can keep a reference in the selector, and use the reference.

```
function Foo(elementId, buttonId) {

    /*...*/

    var self = this;
    this.button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {self.bar();}, false);
}
```

---

Or a more modern solution that doesn't require a variable would be to use `Function.prototype.bind`.

```
function Foo(elementId, buttonId) {

    /*...*/

    this.button.addEventListener('click', this.bar.bind(this), false);
}
```

The `.bind` method returns a new `bar` function with the `this` value bound to whatever you passed it. In this case, it is bound to the original `this` from the constructor.

Comment: Important to note that many browsers still commonly-used (e.g. IE 8, Safari <= 5.1, others) do not support Function.prototype.bind: http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/

Comment: var self = this;
That did it; I didn't even think that 'this' might be referencing the button element. Thanks for your help and the quick response. I'd upvote if I could, but I don't have the rep yet :)

Answer (score 1):

`this` in the event handler is the element that the event was added to.

To access the outer `this`, you need to store it in a separate variable.

Answer (score 0):

`this` in the click handler is the button element not the object, use a variable to reference the object, like `var self = this;`

```
function Foo(elementId, buttonId) {
    var self = this;
    this.element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    this.button = document.getElementById(buttonId);
    this.bar = function() {dosomething};
    this.button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {self.bar();}, false);
}
```

Comment: I found that for using functions (not classes) in JS, you don't need any this. variables, as all variables you define with let inside the function and all the variables you pass to that function are UNIQUE FOR THAT FUNCTION, so EVENT LISTENERS inside that function work, also the classic for loop example works simply by calling the function and giving it an x parameter

Comment: In Oct 4, 2012 at 16:23 we didn't have that option

Comment: Yes, let variables were introduced in CS6.  But they are a better solution in this case